# get array list from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my example I saved complex data on Firebase and I want get it back.

When I am using this code I can get any values stoared in hashmap.

```
for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String: Any] else { continue }
                let title = restDict["title"] as? String
                let genre = restDict["genre"] as? NSDictionary
                let singer = restDict["singer"] as? NSArray

                print(genre?["title"])

            }
```

in my database I also I have Singer as array (id, name, age).

How could I return this values as well?

Comment: What do you mean by an 'array'? Firebase doesn't allow for the storage of native arrays.

Comment: Please share the code of how you saved the data to Firebase. And a snippet of the JSON from your database (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe firebase can store array types, however Firebase does explain how to store a list of values in its documentation: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html
Hope this was helpful :)